# Macro to Record Changes to Range of cells in separate log sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro that creates a log, in a log sheet every time there a cell changed in a specific worksheet.

That macro works really well but unfortunately a little too well!! Because every time I delete a row or a column it makes a record of every cell in that row or column that has been deleted!! (That's lots of cells!! So the spreadsheet just falls over)

Is there a way to make my macro only record that a row has been deleted (rather than every cell in that row? If not... can I just get it to ignore creating a log file if a row or column is deleted?

Or can I limit the code to a particular range. Eg. If I delete a row it only logs that cells A13:BC13 have been deleted

My code that I have used so far is a follows:

```
Const intUsernameColumn = 1
Const intCellRefColumn = 2
Const intNewValueColumn = 3
Const intTimestampColumn = 4

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim shtLog As Worksheet
  Dim cll As Variant
  Dim lngNextRow As Long

  Set shtLog = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")

  For Each cll In Target.Cells
    lngNextRow = shtLog.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], Searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    shtLog.Cells(lngNextRow, intUsernameColumn).Value = Environ("username")
    shtLog.Cells(lngNextRow, intCellRefColumn).Value = cll.Address
    shtLog.Cells(lngNextRow, intNewValueColumn).Value = cll.Value
    shtLog.Cells(lngNextRow, intTimestampColumn).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy hh:mm:ss")
  Next cll
End Sub
```

I'm still fairly new at this so any help would be appreciated

Thanks!!

Comment: I was going to suggest checking if `Target.Address = Target.EntireColumn.Address` but that won't know if you've deleted or added a column.

Answer (score 0):

This is not using a `For` loop - it just determines if multiple cells were updated

If rows or columns have been deleted, or pasted

- It shows total Rows and/or Columns edited
- The value of the first Cell in the Target range

  - If that first Cell has an error it will convert it to the text "Error"

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Const USR_COL = 1
Private Const REF_COL = 2
Private Const VAL_COL = 3
Private Const DT_COL = 4

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim wsLog As Worksheet, nextRow As Long, ref As String

  Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  If IsError(Target.Cells(1)) Then Target.Cells(1) = "Error"

  With Target
     ref = .Address(False, False)
     If .CountLarge > 1 Then ref = "Rows: " & .Rows.Count & ", Columns: " & .Columns.Count
  End With

  With wsLog
     nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, USR_COL).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Cells(nextRow, USR_COL) = Environ("username")
    .Cells(nextRow, REF_COL) = ref
    .Cells(nextRow, VAL_COL) = "Val: """ & Target.Cells(1) & """"
    .Cells(nextRow, DT_COL) = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy hh:mm:ss")
  End With

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

If the change was made to one cell it will show

```
UserName     K9                      Val: "5"         01-May-18 09:31:59
```

Else

```
UserName     Rows: 1, Columns: 2     Val: "10"        01-May-18 09:31:59
UserName     Rows: 3, Columns: 1     Val: "Error"     01-May-18 09:31:59
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this!! I shall give it a go.
I did find a quick work around but this does sound much better.
Cheers!!